# display data from datatable on dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, select, datatable, dropdown

i use datatable plugin to diplay the data from my db. now my problem is when i edit a data it fetch everything except the data for the `select dropdown`

sample i have this displayed in my datatable

REGION IV-A    |    BATANGAS  |   BAUAN   |   CUPANG

and this is what's inside my db.

01  |  5552 | 3320 | 1110

this are the id's of each data that is being displayed on my datatable.

```
$('#region_3 option:selected').val(data['region']);
$('#province_3 option:selected').val(data['province']);
$('#city_3 option:selected').val(data['city']);
$('#barangay_3 option:selected').val(data['barangay']);
```

and this is the code i use to supposedly display on the dropdown. but unfortunately it doesnt display what is on the datatable..

Answer (score 1):

Your code would update value property of the selected option. To achieve the result, You need to apply [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method on the dropdown.

```
$('#region_3').val(data['region']);
$('#province_3').val(data['province']);
$('#city_3').val(data['city']);
$('#barangay_3').val(data['barangay']);
```

Comment: as you can see i already put `.val` method to my code.. but still the data is not being displayed

Comment: @LionSmith is there is an option with the id as value in each dropdown ??

Comment: i actually tried to display the id on my datatable so that when i click my edit function it will fetch the id's but still i got no result.

Comment: the value of each dropdown is the ID of each description.. but i only display the description on my datatable since it is inappropriate to see the ids not their values.